# ValueError: merc projection cannot cross pole

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I am using winpy 3.6 and installed basemap. When I am using basemap it is giving an error.

```
m = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlat=10, urcrnrlat=50,
        llcrnrlon=-160, urcrnrlon=-60, resolution="c")
```

But when i am using "resolution=None" so there is no problem but I cannot call other properties like coastline, boundaries etc.

If somebody can help in this?

Comment: I have installed this module " basemap‑1.1.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl"

Comment: Can you add the error message?
Also how did you install the package?

Comment: File "C:\python3\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 1250, in _readboundarydata
    raise ValueError('%s projection cannot cross pole'%(self.projection))

ValueError: merc projection cannot cross pole

Comment: I have installed it using winpython control panel in Tool. I have downloaded the whl file and then from add packages i have added it

Comment: ok, this might be better placed on the GIS site, but i think your issue might be due to the fact your llcrnrlat value is lower then your urcrnrlat value.

you are trying to define a square box, but you have actually done the inverse, so you are including the entire world except a very small area.

Comment: Correction, your llcrnrlat value is *higher* then your urcrnrlat value

Comment: even i put small bounding box of coordinates, still i am getting the same error

Comment: it doesnt matter how small. you need to have them in the right order. e.g you ll values should be smaller then your ur values. for example these values should work
`llcrnrlat=10, lcrnrlon=100,  urcrnrlat=50, urcrnrlon=150`

Comment: I solved that problem. I updated my numpy version and it starts working fine

Comment: you should write what you did in an answer and then choose it as the correct answer so other people who find this question can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem. I updated my numpy version and it starts working fine

Answer (score 0):

Hard to responced without more details.

But in your code do you have 
`resolution"c"`?

In the very least that should be `resolution="c"`.

Comment: it is small letter "c" or even i m using "i" or "h" it is giving same error with all projection systems but when i am writing resolution=None, it is taking

Comment: that is typo only